# fatal error: utils/jsonb.h: No such file or directory

Tags: json, database, postgresql, compression

I was trying ZSON compression in postgres using this doc: https://sudonull.com/post/77435-ZSON-PostgreSQL-extension-for-transparent-JSONB-compression . However, while running make I got below error:

```
     sudo make install
     gcc -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -- 
     param=ssp- 
     buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0 -Wall -Wmissing- 
     prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format- 
     attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -fPIC -g - 
     O2 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/pgsql/server -I/usr/include/pgsql/internal -D_GNU_SOURCE - 
     I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o zson.o zson.c
     zson.c:6:25: fatal error: utils/jsonb.h: No such file or directory
    #include <utils/jsonb.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    make: *** [zson.o] Error 1
```

any way to avoid/fix the error? The error says the file doesn't exist. However, how can I get this file to make it working.

Comment: This is indicates that the Postgresql development files are not installed. How did you install Postgresql and on what OS and version?

Comment: Or perhaps the headers are installed somewhere else than `/usr/include/pgsql` and you have to tell the build process the correct location.